# Why does this dropdown dissapear?

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I'm working on this fairly simple dropdown and I can't work out why the dropdown dissapears when you hover past the first link?

http://haizel.co.uk/wedding/

You can view it above. CSS below:

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 25px 0;
  font-size: 18px; }

nav ul li ul li {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px; }

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0; }

nav li{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px; }

nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; }

nav ul ul{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 20px; }

nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block; }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dropdown menu is dropping down behind the `<section class="main-content">` content so give your header a higher `z-index`

```
header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Looks OK, although I would add `display: block` to your navigational anchors. `nav a{display: block;}`